# Updating the same property in two places on an MVC form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms, updates

I have two fields on an MVC3 form that must represent the same value.  If one is updated it should update the other and display the correct value (Gotta love requirements).  For what may be obvious reasons, the field (with the second one on the page) does not update properly.  Is there a way to achieve what I need?

For example:

**First Example**

```
 <li class="identifier-controls"            @Model.IdentifierConfigurator.GenerateDataAttributes("ssn")>
        @Html.TextFieldFor("Social Security Number", m => m.SocialSecurityNumber).SSN()
    </li>

may appear twice on that form (In two different spots). (At this point, both of the controls have the same ID and name)
```

OR:

**Second Example**

```
    <li class="identifier-controls"            @Model.IdentifierConfigurator.GenerateDataAttributes("ssn")>
       @Html.TextFieldFor("Social Security Number", m => m.SocialSecurityNumber).SSN()
    </li>
```

and

```
    <li class="identifier-controls"            @Model.IdentifierConfigurator.GenerateDataAttributes("ssn")>
       @Html.TextFieldFor("Social Security Number", m => m.Person.Description.SSN).SSN()
    </li>
```

will appear on the form.  At this point the IDs are different for the input but it will only update on of them.

Here is the HTML that is generated:

```
<ol class="field-list display">

  <li id="party-name"><span class="label">Name</span><span id="FormalDisplayName" class="value" style="width:140px">Guy, Bad</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Aliases</span><span id="AliasNames" class="notentered" style="width:140px">Not entered</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Status</span><span id="PartyStatusName" class="notentered" style="width:140px">Not entered</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Gender</span><span id="Description_Gender" class="notentered" style="width:140px">Not entered</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Juvenile</span><span id="Description_IsJuvenile" class="value" style="width:140px">No</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Ethnicity</span><span id="Description_Ethnicity" class="notentered" style="width:140px">Not entered</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Residential Status</span><span id="Description_ResidentialStatus" class="notentered" style="width:140px">Not entered</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Marital Status</span><span id="Description_MaritalStatus" class="notentered" style="width:140px">Not entered</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Religion</span><span id="Description_Religion" class="notentered" style="width:140px">Not entered</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Citizenship</span><span id="Description_Citizenship" class="notentered" style="width:140px">Not entered</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Birth City</span><span id="Description_BirthCity" class="notentered" style="width:140px">Not entered</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Date of Birth</span><span id="Description_BirthDate" class="notentered" style="width:140px">Not entered</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Date of Death</span><span id="Description_DeathDate" class="notentered" style="width:140px">Not entered</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Est. Age at Incident</span><span id="Description_EstimatedAgeAtIncident" class="notentered" style="width:140px">Not entered</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Adoption Date</span><span id="Description_AdoptionDate" class="notentered" style="width:140px">Not entered</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Multiple Birth</span><span id="Description_MultipleBirthName" class="notentered" style="width:140px">Not entered</span></li>

  <li><span class="label">Email</span><span id="Description_Email" class="notentered" style="width:140px">Not entered</span></li>



    <li><span class="label">Identifiers</span><span id="SuspectIdentifiersDisplay" class="value" style="width:400px">Prof<span class='value-display'>&nbsp;123</span><span class='separator'>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>FBI<span class='value-display'>&nbsp;123</span><span class='separator'>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>SSN<span class='value-display'>&nbsp;222-22-2222</span><span class='separator'>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>ITN<span class='value-display'>&nbsp;123</span><span class='separator'>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>BCI<span class='value-display'>&nbsp;13</span><span class='separator'>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>ID<span class='value-display'>&nbsp;123</span><span class='separator'>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span>DL<span class='value-display'>&nbsp;123</span><span class='separator'>&nbsp;|&nbsp;</span></span></li>

</ol>
```

The only difference between this HTML (this is the html from example two) and the HTML that is generated in the first example is that the two controls have the same ID and name.  Here is what happens in the controller method that is called by the BeginRouteForm html helper when submit is called:

public ActionResult Update(int partyId, FormCollection data)
    {
      var party = Party.Find(partyId).OrNotFound();
      var vm = new PartyEditViewModel(party.Case, party);

```
  try
  {
    UpdateModel(vm, data);

    return JsView("Update.js", party);
  }
  catch (UpdateModelException)
  {
    return JsView("Edit.js", vm);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you also post the html that is generated when your page is loaded?  Additionally, are you looking for the change to happen after the form has been submitted or are you looking for something more dynamic such that if I edit one text field the other changes as well?  Please correct me if I am not understanding your requirements.

Comment: Im just looking for the values to change AFTER the form is submitted.  In our app, once the form is submitted, processing occurs and then the user is taken to a details page which just shows the updated form values as read-only.  When the edit button is clicked again, both of the controls above on the form should contain the same value.  This should occur regardless of which of the fields are updated.

Comment: Ok and in your controller action what parameter(s) are you sending to your post action that processes the update?

Comment: OK I am guessing here but since both controls have the same name and Id when the model is updated it could potentially be grabbing only the first control to bind the model with.  Also can you confirm if when the model is updated from the first control, if the read only display shows the new value in both controls.

Comment: The parameters are the names that you see in the html snippet I added.  They all get posted and then the controller method(also added) does the updating.

Comment: Yes, Once I actually get the value to update, both places on the form show the correct value.  Now, I agree that the same ID/Name is bad and could be causing issues, but that isnt the case in the second example.  Unless, of course, the form somehow knows that it is the same without the ID/Name being the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok it looks like what is causing the issue is that your calls to Html.TextFieldFor may be creating two controls with the same name and Id that bound to to seperate model properties.  If this is the case you will need to correctly prefix the id and name of the controls so that when model binding kicks in, it will bind the values correctly against the model's properties.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm saying

Comment: Ok I think I have figured it out.  The issues are related to the fact that there are two fields with the same name/id (as you mentioned above).  It seems that because the values are filled in when the edit button is clicked, the first control with the value in it will be the value that it uses to update.  Therefore, If I change the value of the first control that appears, then the update will work perfectly and you will notice a change.  If the second control is updated, the first control still has the old value in it and that is the value so the update is not noticed.  Thanks!

Comment: Great glad you were able to figure it out.

Comment: I think a decent way to "hack" around this is to set a blur event on both of the fields so that when one is changed it will automatically update the other field so that this will not be an issue again.

Comment: Yes exactly you will need to use some client side code to manage the change in value of both of the controls.